# Devexpress: how to add points to Chart Control at runtime?

Tags: winforms, charts, devexpress

i'm trying to build a telemetry software using Winform and Devexpress library. Specifically i'm working on a Line Chart Control and what i would like to do is to configure the chart so that it is able to display a data changing in real time.

The graph is generated reading some external sensors that send informations at a rate of 10 values per second.

This is my code for initialize the chart:

```
series1 = new Series("test test", ViewType.Line);

chartControl1.Series.Add(series1);
series1.ArgumentScaleType = ScaleType.Numerical;

((LineSeriesView)series1.View).LineMarkerOptions.Kind = MarkerKind.Triangle;
((LineSeriesView)series1.View).LineStyle.DashStyle = DashStyle.Dash;
((XYDiagram)chartControl1.Diagram).EnableAxisXZooming = true;

chartControl1.Legend.Visibility = DefaultBoolean.False;

chartControl1.Titles.Add(new ChartTitle());
chartControl1.Titles[0].Text = "A Line Chart";

chartControl1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
```

And this is the one that add a new point and remove the first point available  so that the amount of points in my chart is always the same (after a minimum amount of points is reached) and it keeps updating itself displaying the last X seconds of values and discarding the old values.

```
series1.Points.RemoveRange(0, 1);
series1.Points.Add(new SeriesPoint(time, value));

...

AxisXRange.SetMinMaxValues(newFirstTime, time);
```

AxisRange is the following

```
Range AxisXRange
    {
        get
        {
            SwiftPlotDiagram diagram = chartControl1.Diagram as SwiftPlotDiagram;
            if (diagram != null)
                return diagram.AxisX.VisualRange;
            return null;
        }
    }
```

**The problem ** is that this code works temporarily. After some seconds, the chart stop working and a big red cross is displayed over it.

Is there something that i'm missing with its configuration? 
Do you know any better way to realize my task?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: In WinForms, a bit red cross is displayed by a control if an unhanded exception is raised when the control is being painted. In Visual Studio, you can [configure options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x85tt0dd.aspx) so that the debugger will always stop at the unhands exception. This will help you to determine the cause of the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the hint

Comment: @Uranus thanks to your hint i found a problem but now i was thinking: is that the right way to implement the chart? Have you ever tried something like this? I think it has some performance issues after 20 sec of data. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I think you doing it nearly right. Devexpress has an [Article](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E310) about RealTime-Charts. They doing it the same way but using a timer for updating the data. Maybe this would fix your painting problems.